# Run docker run command in python script

Tags: python, docker

I need to run following command inside python script to remove all exisiting docker services

```
import subprocess
bashCommand = "docker service rm $(docker service ls)" 
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  shell=True)
```

This is not giving desired results. Services still exists after running this file.
I am using centos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried you use `subprocess.call` instead?

For example,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("docker rmi $(docker ps -a -q)", shell=True)
```

it works for `rmi` command.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this library](http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/) :

You could loop all services through [services.list()](http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html?highlight=service#docker.models.services.ServiceCollection.list) and rm them with [service.remove()](http://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html?highlight=service#docker.models.services.Service.remove)